# checking if answer right or wrong

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, methods, awt

I have a project which is an quiz that has multiple questions , true/false and fill in the blank, my problem is with the Check answer method.

First I have written the Q's in database with SQL and the columns is as follow
[image]

and there are 2 methods
the first one is for retrieving the questions, choices and right answer

```
public void m() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/quiz?user=root&password=Manager@1");
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stm.executeQuery("Select * from quiz.qs where qid="+ Random());
            
        if (rs1.next()) {
            bg.clearSelection();
            quest.setText(rs1.getString(2));
            r1.setText(rs1.getString(3));
            r2.setText(rs1.getString(4));
            r3.setText(rs1.getString(5));
            r4.setText(rs1.getString(6));
            answer = rs1.getString(7);
            check(answer);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

the second one is for checking if the chosen answer was right , that's the part that I have problem with

```
public void check(String ans) {
    boolean works=false;
    String stuans="";
    if (r1.isSelected()) {
        if (ans.equals(r1.getText())) {
            marks=marks+1;
        }
    } else if (r2.isSelected()) {
        if (ans.equals(r2.getText())) {
            marks=marks+1;   
        }
    } else if (r3.isSelected()) {
        if (ans.equals(r3.getText())) {
            marks=marks+1;  
        }
    } else if (r4.isSelected()) {
        if (ans.equals(r4.getText())) {
            marks=marks+1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(marks);// to check if marks has increased after checking
}
```

whenever I choose the right answer , the marks does not increase.

[image]

that's a pic from the program with GUI , sorry if something is not so clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use == with Strings. Use the .equals method.

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

Comment: I have used .equals but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?